# How to handle Like Unlike of events in listview similar to facebook API call android

Tags: android, http, listview, httpresponse

Currently I am working on a list of event similar to Facebook TimeLine in which user can like/Unlike events.
I have POST/DELETE API calls for the same and Local Database Table for displaying the same.

Currently I am calling API according to user LIKE/DISLIKE and updating Database table after server Responose and  notifying the adapter change but the time utilized in sending Request to server and updating the table is more than 3-4 seconds which seems the implementation slower to like/Unlike the events is there any better way to handle to same?
Similar to FaceBook's super-fast LIKE/UNLIKE response?

Thanks.

Comment: You can assume that it went through in order to set it to like/dislike state, then when you get the response from server you can update it

Comment: I suggest you to use asynkTask to show the progress and display the UI

Comment: @Carnal How to handle the events when user is supposed to like/unlike the same event continuously.. then I need to queue all the requests?

Comment: for continuous save last state of like or unlike. After some time(using timer) send the request to server. If server return positive response then nothing to change, if it negative then revert change.

Comment: Yes, you can call this request in a background thread (eg. asynctask) to the server.

Comment: If I understand the problem well, I think the scenario is there is one "Status post" on the timeline and you need to like/unlike it. So I suggest when user click on Like button.. change the UI as per requirement, make changes in database..and parallel send request to server to like the post.. this way user will see the instant reaction of "Click and Like"...

Answer (score 1):

Just change text of your view to like/unlike and keep the list position of your view, after sometime in background get the positions where the changes are made to like/unlike and get the state of that view, update it to server.